# Is it true that $\int_a^b f(y)y' dx = \int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} f(y)dy$?

Tags: calculus

For a couple of years now I've been using the formula

$$\int_a^b f(y)\frac {dy}{dx} dx = \int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} f(y)dy$$

and if asked about it I'd wave my hand saying it comes from the FTC.

But the FTC really just states that $$\int_a^b \frac {dy}{dx} dx = \int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} dy$$

Is the formula that I've been using correct?  I've never been counted wrong on a math assignment for it.  If it's correct, how would it be proven?

Comment: yes. fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: As long as $f$ is the derivative of another function (which is usually the case) you should be safe.

Comment: @abel Isn't that precisely the FTC handwaving that the OP is trying to avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true: from
$$
F'(y)=f(y)\Leftrightarrow F(y)+c=\int f(y)dy\Leftrightarrow F(y(x))+c=\left.\int f(y)dy\right|_{y=y(x)}
$$
and
$$
D[F(y(x))]=F'(y(x))y'(x)=f(y(x))y'(x)
$$
You get
$$
\int f(y(x))y'(x)dx=\int D[F(y(x))]dx=F(y(x))+c=\left.\int f(y)dy\right|_{y=y(x)}
$$